# How can I push a selected tab update (java swing)?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, updatepanel

I'm trying to update the tab being displayed, however it seems to wait until the end of the method and then update. Is there a way to make the tab being displayed update immediately?

Here is an example of the code where I'm having this issue:

```
private static void someButtonMethod() 
{
    Button = new JButton("My Button");
    Button(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            tabs.setSelectedIndex(1);

            // Do some other things (In my case run a program that takes several seconds to run).
            runProgram();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, to see what you mean by "the end of the method"!

Comment: I have added my example.

Comment: Does the tab get selected after the program you run finishes?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I would try tab.invalidate()

Comment: Does tabs.setSelectedIndex(1); not perform immediatelly?

Comment: Yes thats correct, it doesn't seem to perform immediately. It waits until my program has finished running then shows the update.

Comment: I just tried tab.invalidate() and it still didn't work. It's as if the GUI freezes up.

Comment: @Jon W 09 what processes take that long time, because maybe is there needed SwingWorker, maybe not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that the method is being executed in the Event Dispatch thread, and any repaint operations **will also occur in this thread**.  One "solution" is to update the tab index and then schedule the remaining work to be invoked later on the EDT; this should cause the tab state to be updated immediately; e.g.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  tab.setSelectedIndex(1);

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Do remaining work.
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment below an example of how to invoke a `SwingWorker` in order to call your runProgram method would look something like this:

```
// Typed using Void because runProgram() has no return value.
new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
  protectedVoid doInBackground() {
    runProgram();
    return null; // runProgram() doesn't return anything so return null.
  }

  protected void done() {
    // Called on the EDT when the background computation has completed.
    // Could insert code to update UI here.
  }  
}.execute()
```

However, I sense a bigger problem here: The fact that you are seeing a significant delay in updating the tab makes me think you are performing long running calculations on the EDT.  If this is the case you should consider performing this work on a background thread.  Take a look at the [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been looking at the class you provided however I'm having some difficulty understanding how I could make use of it in my program. Please could you advise on this?

Comment: How exactly are you having difficulty?  Are you referring to the SwingWorker class or the code snippet above?

Comment: The SwingWorker class. Essentially I want to run the method `runProgram()` in the background thread, however after examining the examples provided I can't understand how to achieve this.